# Creating Estimation Windows based on a Criteria (DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking at how I can select a couple of rows (specifically -15 until -5) based on a specific criteria.

We have a list of Events (dates) and a large DataFrame with all BitCoin orders, ordered by Date. In this DataFrame we have a column that marks a row with 'True' if the value in Events is found in the DataFrame.

What I want to do is when 'True' is found in this column, that Python selects the rows from 15 rows (-15) before the True until the 5 (-5) rows before the True. In total we have 42 events and our goal is to create a new DataFrame that we will use calculate the descriptive statistics of these values.

[image: Image of Our DataFrame]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. FYI. It's normally easier to answer these when you post some code that generates some test dataset :)

First, here is a dataset. Here we're basically trying to select based on the True values. But we only want 1 before and 1 after, so we shouldn't see any gone.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['gone', False],
    ['a', False],
    ['abb', True],
    ['a', False],
    ['gone', False],
    ['gone', False],
    ['a', False],
    ['abbb', True],
    ['a', False],
    ['gone', False],
    ['gone', False]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['label', 'indicator'])

ranges = df[df['indicator']].index.values
```

Next we generate a range of rows we're interested in. For your case you would want to set num_before and num_after differently. You can probably compress the code somewhat but I thought the steps are easier to understand this way.

```
num_before = 1
num_after = 1

indexes = [range(x-num_before, x+num_after+1) for x in ranges] #+1 due to the behaviour of range
x = [list(rang) for rang in indexes]
i = np.array(x).reshape(-1)
```

Finally we select the rows matching the generated list we just made.

```
df.iloc[i]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This solves the problem perfectly. I keep your feedback in mind and add in more information next time I post on StackOverflow.